# How can I improve the numerical results while working Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, precision-and-accuracy

I'm trying to solve nonlinear equations using Newton-type methods with very high accuracy using Mathematica. I found many research papers in which the numerical results are calculated with very high accuracy. e.g. To solve the equation 
$$e^{-x}+\sin(x)-2=0\text{ with initial guess }x_0=-1.$$
Many authors evaluated its functional value after some iterations up to $10^{-300}$ and less than this. But with the same function and same initial guess, I could not get the functional value better than $10^{-16}$. Why? Is there any special coding to increase the accuracy of the result.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: With the errors, did you mean `1e-300, 1e-16` as in $10^{-300},\,10^{-16}$?

Comment: yes, it means 10^(-300) and so on.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question "Why?" without seeing how you coded your Newton-type methods.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
FindRoot[Exp[-x] + Sin[x] - 2 == 0, {x, -1}, WorkingPrecision -> 500]
```

Comment: I'm using the following code :

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) as long as you provide a domain restriction:

```
root = x /. First @ Solve[Exp[-x]+Sin[x]-2==0 && -2<x<0]
```

> Root[{1 - 2 E^#1 + E^#1 Sin[#1] &, -1.05412712409121289977}]

The nice thing about the [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) representation above is that it behaves like an exact expression. Anywhere you can use an exact expression (like [`Pi`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pi)), you can instead use the above [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) object. For example:

```
N[root]
N[root, 100]
Integrate[x^root, {x, 1, 2}]
Minimize[x^2 - 2 root x + 1, x]
```

> -1.05413
>
> -1.054127124091212899766844310942376610765302238222244358374175157259667078894540095490830534013697076
>
> (-1 + 2^(1 + Root[{1 + E^#1 (-2 + Sin[#1]) &, -1.05412712409121289977}]))/(1 +
>     Root[{1 + E^#1 (-2 + Sin[#1]) &, -1.05412712409121289977}])
>
> {1 - Root[{1 - 2 E^#1 + E^#1 Sin[#1] &, -1.05412712409121289977}]^2, {x -> 
>      Root[{1 - 2 E^#1 + E^#1 Sin[#1] &, -1.05412712409121289977}]}}